# lambda object + c callback sigsegv

Tags: c++, c, c++11, lambda

If I implement a C callback like this:

```
register_callback([](/*some args*/){/*some stuff*/});
```

I get a SIGSEGV when it triggers, but if I register it like this:

```
auto const f([](/*some args*/){/*some stuff*/});

register_callback(f);
```

Then it works fine. Of particular interest (to me) is the stack trace produced by the address sanitizer:

```
ASAN:SIGSEGV
=================================================================
==22904==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7f1582c54701 (pc 0x7f1582c54701 sp 0x7f1582c544a8 bp 0x7f1582c54510 T2)
    #0 0x7f1582c54700 ([stack:22906]+0x7fc700)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV ??:0 ??
```

It looks, as if the function pointer pointed to the stack. Does pushing a lambda onto the stack push code onto the stack? Since I capture nothing the location of the function pointer is a mystery to me. What is happening? No optimization flags were used. I am not looking for workarounds.

EDIT: Apparently the '+' was the key to a working example. I don't know why it is necessary. Remove the '+' and the example with compile but SIGSEGV will be triggered with both `clang-3.5` and `gcc-4.9`.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include <ostream>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  auto const curl(curl_easy_init());

  if (curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "cnn.com");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

/*
    auto const f([](char* const ptr, size_t const size, size_t const nmemb,
      void* const data)
      {
        *static_cast<::std::ostream*>(data) << ptr;

        return size * nmemb;
      }
    );

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, +f);
*/

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
      +[](char* const ptr, size_t const size, size_t const nmemb,
        void* const data)
        {
          *static_cast<::std::ostream*>(data) << ptr;

          return size * nmemb;
        }
    );

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &::std::cout);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be too long, I think, the lambda serves as a callback from libcurl. The greater part is a web service. Maybe I can cook something up.

Comment: @user1095108 Does libcurl have a C++11 API? (I believe you need to share more of the *actual* surrounding code.)

Comment: @molbdnilo It has wrappers, of course, but I used the plain C API. I took advantage of the same calling conventions and lambda-to-function-pointer conversion, of course.

Comment: The problem would make sense if the function pointer did live on the stack, in the first example the temporary closure object is destroyed as soon as `register_callback` is called. Whereas in the second the object has its lifetime extended until the end of scope.

Comment: @user1095108 Posting a SSCE doesn't mean posting your source code. It means that you should reimplement and reproduce the problem **outside** your code base. Any easy way would be `extern C {typedef void (*some_func)(void); void do_some_func(some_func foo);} int main() { do_some_func([](){std::cout<<"Hello World" << std::endl;}}`

Comment: I have provided it now.

Comment: `char* const ptr` ... what?  Why?  Is that data supposed to be immutable, or not?

Comment: @Yakk The signature is specified by `cUrl`, I am not changing the data.

Comment: `size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)` lacks any mention of `const`.  You added `const` to the parameters, but not to what they are pointing.  I'd make it `char const*const ptr` at the least (as you probably know, `const` won't change the ABI for a function pointer).  Similarly you can change the `void*` from `void*const` to `decltype(&std::cout)` (safer than your manual inversion of the `&::std::cout` cast-to-`void*`)

Comment: @Yakk You are, of course, right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curl_easy_setopt` is defined as (in `curl/easy.h`):

```
CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);
```

That means that the third argument `param` must be of a type that can be passed as a C variadic. Unfortunately, while `curl_easy_setopt` is expecting a function pointer, passing class objects (and lambdas are class objects) is "*conditionally-supported with implementation-deﬁned semantics*" (**[expr.call]**/7), so the compiler accepts it but then `curl_easy_setopt` tries to interpret the lambda object as a function pointer, with catastrophic results.

The object that you actually pass is a captureless lambda which means that it is an empty class object, of size 1 byte (all most-derived objects must be at least one byte in size). The compiler will promote that argument to a word-size integer (4 bytes on 32-bit, 8 bytes on 64-bit) and either pass `0` or leave that register/stack slot unset, meaning that garbage gets passed (since the lambda doesn't actually use its memory footprint when called).

Comment: I thought a lambda to pointer conversion would be forced when calling into C, but apparently not :( Thanks! BTW: What did I push onto the stack?

Comment: @user1095108 it would be if `param` was a typed parameter, but as it's variadic it's your responsibility to ensure you pass an argument of exactly the type that curl expects.

Answer (score 2):

I've just write a similar lambda with libcurl, and got crash, after checking carefully, I got the following code working like charm.

The magic is, add the leading `+` at the non-captured lambda expression, which will trigger conversion to plain C function pointer.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
  /* NOTE: Leader '+' trigger conversion from non-captured Lambda Object to plain C pointer */
  +[](void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) -> size_t {
    // invoke the member function via userdata
    return size * nmemb;
  });
```

My understand is, the `curl_easy_setopt()` wants a `void*`, not an explicit function type, so the compiler just gives the address of lambda OBJECT; if we do function pointer operation on lambda object, the compiler will return the function pointer from lambda object.

Comment: No, it expects a function pointer, so putting a lambda in there, even converted, could be wrong. You need an extern "C" function pointer.